# Promise timeouts and WS.get Timeout in PlayFramework 2.1 JAVA

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, promise

I am trying to access to an URL using WS on Play Framework 2.1 using JAVA api.

Here is what I want:

1. Some where in the code, start a WS request using `WS.get()` (I set timeout **1000ms**)
2. If WS.get times out or another exception happens, I don't want my Promise throw an exception (since my flow reqiures it that way) So I use `Promise.recover()` to wrap that promise with another. Which returns a `null` Reponse object in case of failures.
3. Some where else in code I want to "get" my Response. I wait for **5000ms** but what I get is `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5000 milliseconds]`

**How?** `WS.get()` timesout after **1000ms** and since it throws an `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: No response received after 1000` it is catched by my recover function. It returns a null response instead of an exception.

So promise is "completed" after 1000ms at most. **Why it times out and throws an exception after 5000 ms?**

Code:

```
    Logger.info("Fetch started: " + new Date().toString());
Promise<WS.Response> p1 = WS.url("http://athena.ics.forth.gr:9090/RDF/VRP/Examples/tap.rdf").setTimeout(1000).get();
Promise<WS.Response> p2 = p1.recover(new Function<Throwable, WS.Response>() { 
  @Override
  public Response apply(Throwable a) throws Throwable {
    Logger.error("Promise thrown an exception so I will return null. " + new Date().toString() + " " + System.currentTimeMillis(), a);
    return null;
  }
});

try {
  /* This should return null or valid response but shouldn't throw an exception */
  Response r = p2.get(5000L);
  Logger.info(r.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
  /* Sholdn't happen! */
  Logger.error("Outer exception: " + " " + System.currentTimeMillis(), e);
}
Logger.error("Fetch finished: " + new Date().toString() + " " + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Output I get:

```
[info] application - Fetch started: Tue Mar 19 10:04:42 EET 2013
[error] application - Outer exception:  1363680287626
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:96) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:58) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:86) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:86) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread$$anon$3.block(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:173) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:2803) [scala-library.jar:na]
[error] application - Fetch finished: Tue Mar 19 10:04:47 EET 2013 1363680287627
[error] application - Promise thrown an exception so I will return null. Tue Mar 19 10:04:47 EET 2013 1363680287627
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: No response received after 1000
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider$ReaperFuture.run(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1809) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
```

Even I wait for promise2 and promise2 is "recover wrapped promise1" recover function runs AFTER exception is thrown.

Comment: setTimeout() sets a connnection timeout. So it could be that your server is responding but it takes longer than 5s to download the file?

Comment: @Fabian setTimeout also sets request timeout: [source](https://github.com/gre/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS.scala#L61) After 1000ms it throws a timeout exception because of request timeout. (Or I get something seriosly wrong and that is possible.) But `recover()` doesn't "handle" it. I added some output to question.